# Casting List<Object> to List<Whatever>

Tags: apex

Just looking to see if anyone has ideas for this I have a method that splits a List into a List of Lists of close to even size.

```
public static List<List<Object>> splitList(List<Object> InputList,Integer Count){
    List<List<Object>> ObjectList = new List<List<Object>>();
    for(Integer i = 0;i < Count && i < InputList.size();i++){
        ObjectList.add(new List<Object>());
    }
    for(Integer i = 0;i < InputList.Size();i++){
        ObjectList[Math.mod(i, Count)].add(InputList[i]);
    }
    return ObjectList;
}
```

But when I return the list I can't unless I'm missing a trick here just cast it like below

```
List<List<String>> ObjectListList = (List<List<String>>) ApexHelper.splitList(test,3);
```

What would be the best way on converting this other than do multiple for loops like below?

```
List<List<Object>> ObjectListList = ApexHelper.splitList(test,3);
List<List<String>> StringListList = new List<List<String>>();
for(List<Object> ObjectList : ObjectListList){
    List<String> StringList = new List<String>();
    for(Object o : ObjectList){
        StringList.add((String) o);
    }
    StringListList.add(StringList);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until Apex allows user-defined generic classes and methods, you can't really do this in a simple way.  You could modify your method to actually return a `List<List<T>>` of a specified type which should allow it to be cast to that type after being returned, unfortunately there isn't a way to have a particular object return its own type so you have to have the user provide it:

```
public static List<List<Object>> splitList(List<Object> InputList,Integer Count, string listType){
    List<List<Object>> ObjectList = (List<List<Object>>)Type.ForName('List<List<' + listType + '>>').newInstance();
    Type innerListType = Type.ForName('List<' + listType + '>');
    for(Integer i = 0;i < Count && i < InputList.size();i++){
        ObjectList.add((List<Object>)innerListType.newInstance());
    }
    for(Integer i = 0;i < InputList.Size();i++){
        ObjectList[Math.mod(i, Count)].add(InputList[i]);
    }
    return ObjectList;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to cast from this either there isn't any special casting method I need to do or is the below right? @IllusiveBrian

`List<List<String>> ObjectListList = (List<List<String>>) ApexHelper.splitList(test,3);`

Comment: @KarlLivesey My bad, didn't do the same thing to the lists being added to the main list.

Comment: Yep Works I'm just glad I don't need to make a special splitter for each type of data or object I want to push through.

Comment: I suppose the only alternative would be to pass in both lists in the input then clone them?

Comment: @KarlLivesey I think that would work.  You could also force a `TypeException` by casting the list to something else and parse the message to find the concrete type of the list.

Comment: That sounds great in theory but I would dread the day they change the format of the message T_T

Comment: @KarlLivesey Yeah, it's one of a bunch of useful information that isn't accessible directly but Exceptions can expose.